# Is it appropriate to use difference scores in this context?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, accuracy, dependent-variable, rating

I am trying to compare the level of rating accuracy of two groups of participants (say Sample A and B). The study design is as is: I asked a consumer panel to rate how much they liked three products. I then asked participants in Sample A and B to guess how the consumer panel rated these products. I do not really care about the rating of the panel per say; mainly, I want to know to what extent Sample A and B differed in their predictive accuracy.

With this in mind, is it acceptable to build a DV that looks like this: DV = [predicted rating - average actual consumer rating], and then compare Sample A and B with a mixed ANOVA: 2 (Sample A / Sample B) x 3 (Product 1 / 2 / 3)? Or should I avoid the difference score, and include the consumer panel in my model: mixed ANOVA with DV = [rating]; and IVs = 3 (Consumer Panel / Sample A / Sample B) x (Product 1 / 2 / 3)?

Either way, I plan to follow-up with pairwise comparisons to see how Sample A & B differ for each product, but the difference score allows me to focus purely on the level of accuracy, rather than the actual rating, which is what I really care about.

A large body of literature advises against difference scores as dependent variables. That said, I feel that the concerns they raise may not apply in this context (what I'm doing is more akin to centering the data). But is my intuition right? Or should I absolutely keep the Consumer Panel in the model?

Comment: Have you tried looking at inter-rater reliability, for example Cohen's Kappa?

Comment: IRR for what measure? I'm familiar with Cohen's Kappa but I am not sure how it applies here. I'm curious to hear what you have in mind though.